# For loop function call file parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recognize that this code is wildly inefficient.

I'm at a complete loss here, and I'm planning to remove the function and just make the code procedural in main.  But I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm seeing here.  The loop in main() runs and calls matchName().  matchName() executes it's loop then, when it should return for the next "vtRow", instead it just stops executing.  So the output is the first record of vtData and every record from adData.

```
import csv, re

def main():
    #1st word
    oneWord = re.compile( '\A([\w]+)' )
    #1st 3
    first3 = re.compile( '\A([\w]{3})' )
    #last 3
    last3 = re.compile( '(?=([\w]{3})$)' )

    mArray = [ oneWord, first3, last3 ]
    adFile =  open('adData.csv', 'rb')
    adFields = ('lName','fName','cNum','addy','city','state','zip','phone','sex')
    adData = csv.reader(adFile, dialect='excel')

    vtFile =  open('data360.csv','rb')
    vtFields = ('ref','fName','lName')
    vtData = csv.reader(vtFile, dialect='excel')

    for vtRow in vtData:
        matchName(vtRow, adData, mArray) # appears that this runs once and exits

def matchName(curVtRow, adData, mArr):
    lName = curVtRow[4].lower()
    fName = curVtRow[3].lower()
    Posib = []

    for row in adData:
        cName = row[0].lower() 
        print "vt " + lName + " ; ad " + cName
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What line does it stop at? Could you mark it in the code? Show input and output?

Comment: it exits gracefully at matchname(vtRow, adData, mArray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that looping with `adData` causes `adFile` to be read, and so after the first call to `matchName()` the file will have been read all the way and thus `adData` won't be looped over as `adData.next()` won't result in anything (and thus the `print` statement will not be executed). I suggest placing `adFile.seek(0)` after the call to `matchName()`. Note that just recreating `adData` won't work; I discovered recently that a csv reader updates its underlying object's file position rather than keeping track of it on its own.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll have to do a little more reading in the docs, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is doing a `seek(0)` on the underlying file for a CSV reader guaranteed to work? Once the CSV reader reaches the end of file, I would half expect it to stop permanently

Comment: @SimonCallan Yes, because `adData.next()` (`next(adData)` in Python 3) just wraps a call to `adFile.next()` (or rather, `Reader_iternext()` since `csv` wraps a C extension) with some additional processing to parse the comma-separated values. http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9046ef201591/Modules/_csv.c#l800. That hasn't changed since the `csv` module was introduced 10 years ago: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cc35ed2b26a8/Modules/_csv.c#l626 (or if it did change, they reverted the change at some point.)

Comment: changing the loop to: matchName(vtRow, adData, mArray)\n adFile.seek(0) executes, and is currently creating a 600Million line text file... ^C

Comment: (Well, I suppose the values aren't necessarily comma-separated, depending on the dialect, but in my opinion a file like that shouldn't really be called a CSV file. It's like storing a JPEG in a file with a PNG extension.)

Comment: @Brian That's probably because the program doesn't appear to be printing only when the names match up, so it will print a number of lines equal to (lines in `vtFile`)*(lines in `adFile`).

Comment: @JAB Yes, that was intended for troubleshooting.  The matching stuff is taken care of in another function call, not included here.  Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @JAB So, it's an undocumented implementation detail in the C libraries. Is the same feature implemented in jython, or is it going to behave differently?

Comment: @SimonCallan It appears to work the same way (http://sourceforge.net/p/jython/svn/7292/tree/trunk/jython/src/org/python/modules/_csv/PyReader.java#l69).